# Connection to Website possible in Chrome App but not in standalone app

Tags: advanced-rest-client

I am testing links from a server which is only reachable via a VPN.
The test runs perfectly in the chrome app, but when I run it in the standalone app, I get the message:

```
The requested URL can't be reached

The service might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

Connection closed without sending a data
```

Does anyone knows why this is happening and how I could possibly solve it?

I have the latest release of the chrome app and standalone app and I am using a Windows 10 64bit machine.